# What's the difference between image and default:image in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

What is the difference between this configuration:

```
image: python:latest
```

and this:

```
default:
    image: python:latest
```

I have created a single `.gitlab-yml` file with both of these options and cannot really see any major difference.

Is there any benefit of using `default:image` key in `.gitlab-ci.yml` instead of just `image`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation, the correct way to specify a default image is by using the `default` keyword:

> Use image to specify a Docker image that the job runs in.
> **Keyword type**: Job keyword. You can use it only as part of a job or in the default section.
>
> [Source: the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#image)

Like this:

```yaml
default:
    image: python-latest
```

---

Using the keyword `image` globally [is deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#deprecated-keywords).